# `Type L: not enough input` when to unpack the target data

Tags: php, unpack

I get the job done to parse data from target file in binary form with the help of stackoverflow's friends.

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen('data', 'rb');
    fread($handle,64);
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $bytes= fread($handle,32);
        print_r(unpack("La/fb/fc/fd/fe/ff/fg/fh",$bytes));
        echo "<br/>";
        }
    echo "finish";
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

I got the result ,one last bug remains here that can't solve myself.
1.why  unpack(): Type L: not enough input, need 4, have 0 ?
2.how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
while ($bytes = fread($handle, 32)) {
    print_r(unpack("La/fb/fc/fd/fe/ff/fg/fh",$bytes));
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

`feof($handle)` doesn't become true until *after* you've tried to read at the end of the file.

So you're performing an extra `fread()`, which returns `false`, and then trying to unpack an empty byte string.